# Flex order until outside the parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I want to use flex order until outside the parent element

```
<div class="flex-wrap">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="first"></div>
            <div class="second"></div>          
        </div>

        <div class="third">
            <img>
        </div>
 </div>
```

In this situation, I applied css in flex-wrap class like this.

```
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
```

Now it shows like,

first 
second 
third

How can I order like,

first 
third 
second 
?

I tried order value in CSS, in many ways...
but it didn't work.

Comment: Use bootstrap order classes  Refer the documentation [BootstrapOrder](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/#order)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:contents` to "open" the internal wrapper and then `order` to re-arrange the elements in the overall wrapper.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: contents;
}

.flex-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.second {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-wrap">
  <div class="flex-container">
    <div class="first">First</div>
    <div class="second">Second</div>
  </div>

  <div class="third">
    Third
  </div>
</div>
```